# why can't I get my maui app to deploy on release mode?

Tags: android, maui

I've been trying to debug the release version of my Maui app, but am new to Maui and Android development and don't quite understand what's causing these errors.

```
02-27 12:50:57.302  pixel_5_-_api_34    Error   11319   monodroid   Could not load type 'Castle_Kroslak_Mobile__2._0_.MainApplication, Castle Kroslak Mobile (2.0), Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Skipping JNI registration of type 'crc64c5ded23b5d64deba/MainApplication'.
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
02-27 12:50:47.757  pixel_5_-_api_34    Error   11039   WorkSourceUtil  Could not find package: Castle_Kroslak.Castle_Kroslak
```

I've been searching for solutions online and tried adjusting the android manifest and csproj settings. The application simply opens and then closes immediately.

Edit: After turning on AOT and LLVM it no longer crashes but instead lingers on the splash screen with the logs running through the same warnings.

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
03-01 10:54:42.534  pixel_5_-_api_34    Warning 16382   ziparchive  Unable to open '/data/app/~~Xnw-lKj4ELpfX-IhMlcTCg==/com.companyname.castle_kroslak_mobile_2.x0_-sYV73i0LrqQOXctW9i8-Uw==/split_config.xxhdpi.dm': No such file or directory
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
03-01 10:54:42.534  pixel_5_-_api_34    Warning 16382   ziparchive  Unable to open '/data/app/~~Xnw-lKj4ELpfX-IhMlcTCg==/com.companyname.castle_kroslak_mobile_2.x0_-sYV73i0LrqQOXctW9i8-Uw==/split_config.xxhdpi.dm': No such file or directory
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
03-01 10:54:42.533  pixel_5_-_api_34    Warning 16382   ziparchive  Unable to open '/data/app/~~Xnw-lKj4ELpfX-IhMlcTCg==/com.companyname.castle_kroslak_mobile_2.x0_-sYV73i0LrqQOXctW9i8-Uw==/split_config.x86_64.dm': No such file or directory
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
03-01 10:54:42.533  pixel_5_-_api_34    Warning 16382   ziparchive  Unable to open '/data/app/~~Xnw-lKj4ELpfX-IhMlcTCg==/com.companyname.castle_kroslak_mobile_2.x0_-sYV73i0LrqQOXctW9i8-Uw==/split_config.x86_64.dm': No such file or directory
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
03-01 10:54:42.532  pixel_5_-_api_34    Warning 16382   ziparchive  Unable to open '/data/app/~~Xnw-lKj4ELpfX-IhMlcTCg==/com.companyname.castle_kroslak_mobile_2.x0_-sYV73i0LrqQOXctW9i8-Uw==/split_config.en.dm': No such file or directory
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
03-01 10:54:42.531  pixel_5_-_api_34    Warning 16382   ziparchive  Unable to open '/data/app/~~Xnw-lKj4ELpfX-IhMlcTCg==/com.companyname.castle_kroslak_mobile_2.x0_-sYV73i0LrqQOXctW9i8-Uw==/split_config.en.dm': No such file or directory
```

From my understand I thought .dm files were deprecated and that androids load off of apk's and aab's.

Comment: 1. Is it running well under Debug Mode? 2. Try to add `<AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>` to project file

Comment: Yeah it runs fine in debug mode. I'll try the LinkMode and get back.       Edit: No change in behavior I'm scrubbing the logcat again today to see if there are anymore relevant messages but those are the only errors.

Comment: Try to to disable AOT like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77682619/19902734)?

Comment: So I went and check my AOT yesterday and turning on AOT and LLVM makes it not crash but now it lingers on the splash screen